# What is the difference between constant named constructor and static constant field below?

Tags: dart

What is the difference between `a` and `b` below?

```
class ImmutablePoint {
  const ImmutablePoint(this.x, this.y);

  final int x;
  final int y;

  const ImmutablePoint.originA() : this(0, 0);
  static const ImmutablePoint originB = const ImmutablePoint(0, 0);
}

void main() {
  const a = ImmutablePoint.originA();
  const b = ImmutablePoint.originB;
}
```

Comment: Note that `static const ImmutablePoint originB = const ImmutablePoint(0, 0);` can be simplified as `static const ImmutablePoint originB = ImmutablePoint(0, 0);` due to the smartness of Dart compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant variable defines and names a single value.

The `const` constructor defines a way to create *new* values.
If that constructor is invoked as `const ImmutablePoint.originA()` then, because of constant canonicalization, it creates the same constant value that the variable contains. *However*, you can also call `new ImmutablePoint.originA()` (with or without the `new`) and get a *new* instance which is not identical to any other point object.

A Dart constructor being `const` means that it *can* be invoked using `const`, not that it *must*.

Answer (score 1):

From a literal perspective, one is a constructor and the other is a static variable. The constructor allows you to define constants, and the static variable already is a constant. That much should be fairly self-explanatory.

From a performance perspective? Both values resolve to the same constant-defined object:

```dart
const ImmutablePoint(0, 0);
```

Thanks to Dart's canonical constant feature, everything that references this constant class with the same values `0,0` (including other calls to `ImmutablePoint.originA()` or even `ImmutablePoint(0, 0)`) will be reduced to point to the same compile-time constant. So from a practical point of view, both the parameterless `const` constructor and the `static const` variable result in virtually identical compiled code and, therefore, performance.

*(Though from a strictly nit-picky point of view, the `static const` might be compiled to include a static reference to the `ImmutablePoint` type before referencing the constant. I'm not knowledgeable enough with how Dart compiles these situations to say that for certainty, but I can tell you that even if it does happen, the performance hit for a static type reference will be in the "nanoseconds-or-less" tier of negligible. Don't micro-optimize, just use whatever approach you deem more readable or convenient.)*